# How to open PYW files on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pygame

So, I am extremely new to Python. I just downloaded a file from http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/fa303/pgs/tutorial.html. It is a PYW file. It is a recreation of the game Super Mario Brothers. I have Python 3 and Pygame already installed. The folder is on my desktop, and I am currently trying to figure out how I can run the game for a test.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Windows, run the command "pythonw (name of PYW file)" from "cmd.exe". PYW files don't need cmd.exe so you can close out of it.
If you are on Linux or Mac OS X, just rename the PYW"example.PY" file to a PY file and run it from the console. Don't close the console here because it is no longer a PYW file. For the explanations, scroll down.
**Explanations:**

PYW files are just meant "Python Script Without Console". So running a PYW file will not show the console but running a PY file do show a console. PYW files only work in Windows and are not available in Mac and Linux systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it when I get home!

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, but after changing the the file type to .py when I click on it just opens up in my text editor. How to I open it with the console?

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: In Windows Type "Windows Key(Key with Windows Icon) + R" and type in "cmd" and type the Enter key on the keyboard. Then, run "pythonw [filename]". If you are using Windows, you can change the python filename back to PYW.

Comment: PYW cannot be used(it can be run but will need the console to be open) on Mac and Linux.

Comment: I am using Mac. So, I tried running it through terminal but I have no idea how to target the file since it is in a fold on my desktop. I am new to terminal also. I just got into the whole computer developing world 2 months ago. Help please!

Comment: Here is a list of important Mac terminal commands(Mac terminal is a lot like linux terminal): http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=The-10-Most-Important-Linux-Commands